# Safe literal_eval with potential for indexing

Tags: python, eval, trusted-vs-untrusted

I am looking for a way to evaluate string syntax that allows for indexing.

Example:

```
string = '[1,2,3][0]'
foo = literal_eval( string )
```

In this case, I want foo to equal `1`

ast literal_eval does not support this because

[It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

The **code is untrusted** so I cannot use the python `eval()` function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The `ast` module provides parsing functions.

Comment: Can you use a template application such as Jinja2 or do you have to stick with the standard library?

Comment: I can use a template application - key things are making sure it isn't a security risk with untrusted code. Any thoughts on how to make it happen?

Comment: You could write your own parser with [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark). Or any other parser generator.